# Как поделить массив на блоки?

Tags: python, массивы, numpy, матрицы

Я использую библиотеку [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/). Массив был создан с помощью метода [`numpy.zeros()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html). Мне надо поделить его на блоки

```
[[  0.   7.   2.   3.   6.   7.   8.   9.  12.  13.  14.  15.  18.  19.  20.  21.]
 [ 24.  25.  26.  27.  30.  31.  32.  33.  36.  37.  38.  39.  42.  43.  44.  45.]
 [  1.   2.   3.   5.   0.   5.   3.   6.  14.  55.  99.  66.   5.  87.  65.  45.]]
```

Таким образом

```
[[[ 0  7  2  3]
 [ 6  7  8  9]
 [12 13 14 15]
 [18 19 20 21]]

[[24 25 26 27]
 [30 31 32 33]
 [36 37 38 39]
 [42 43 44 45]]

[[ 1  2  3  5]
 [ 0  5  3  6]
 [14 55 99 66]
 [ 5 87 65 45]]]
```

Как я могу это сделать?

Comment: `arr.reshape(3,4,4)`

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь функцией [`reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html):

```
массив.reshape(3, 4, 4)
```

Метод `reshape` принимает новые размерности массива и возвращает view object на старый массив, либо копию старого массива (новой размерности).

Существует две эквивалентные записи:

```
массив.reshape(3, 4, 4)
numpy.reshape(массив, (3, 4, 4))
```

---

Полный пример кода:

```
import numpy as np

source = np.array(
    [[0, 7, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 12, 13, 14, 15, 18, 19, 20, 21],
     [24, 25, 26, 27, 30, 31, 32, 33, 36, 37, 38, 39, 42, 43, 44, 45],
     [1, 2, 3, 5, 0, 5, 3, 6, 14, 55, 99, 66, 5, 87, 65, 45]]
)
result = source.reshape(3, 4, 4)
print(result)
```

[Онлайн проверка](https://ideone.com/0R28os)

---

Интересный факт: в качестве одной из размерностей можно передать `-1`, тогда соответствующая размерность будет вычислена исходя из числа элементов в массиве.

---

Другие методы/свойства, которые могут быть полезными:

- свойство [`numpy.shape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html) — размерность массива, аналогично позволяет изменять размерность массиав
- метод [`numpy.resize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.resize.html) — изменяет размерность и размер массива
- метод [`numpy.ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) — превращает любой массив в одномерный